# How do I exclude the male rows of the data frame, DF, in R, without using the following code; Female <- DF[(DF$Gender == 'Female'),]

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my attempt at the question, but i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
Gender <- c('Male','Male','Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female')
Height <- c('183', '180', '185', '170', '165', '167')

DF <- data.frame(Gender, Height)

Male <- DF[(DF$Gender == 'Male'),]

Exclude_male <- DF[!Male]
```

Comment: With `dplyr()` this comes very easily `DF %>% filter(Gender != "Male")`

Comment: The way you define `Male`, as `DF[(DF$Gender == 'Male'),]`, it is a data frame. So `!Male` doesn't make a lot of sense, - the `!` only makes sense applied to a logical vector, not a whole data frame. That's why your attempt isn't working.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the point of the question is, but one thing you could do is define a logical vector which is TRUE for the male rows and FALSE for the female rows:

```
is_male = DF$Gender == 'Male'
# note this is the same code you used in your "Male <-" line, 
# I'm just giving a name to a smaller part of it so we can re-use it

# Now you can define the `Male` and `Female` subsets using `is_male`:
Male = DF[is_male, ]
Female = DF[!is_male, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other solutions, both with `subset`.

```
Female1 <- subset(DF, Gender != 'Male')
Female2 <- subset(DF, Gender == 'Female')

identical(Female1, Female2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is other code option for keep the values that you want.

```
Only_female <- subset(DF, Gender == 'Female', select = c(Gender, Height))
```